# Basic usage of /etc/cron/ (d): correct pattern for /etc/cron (daily/weekly/monthly)

Tags: cron, filenames, variable-substitution, shebang, syntax

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash and I've created this extensionless, shebangless file `/etc/cron.daily/cron_daily`:

```
for dir in "$drt"/*/; do
if pushd "$dir"; then
wp plugin update --all --allow-root
wp core update --allow-root
wp language core update --allow-root
wp theme update --all --allow-root
popd
fi
done
"$rse"
```

The reason I do it is to be less dependent on `crontab`.

I'd like to ask if the naming of the file is safe, and if the overall syntax and variable expansions are okay.

---

<sub>The `drt` and `rse` variables were already exported after their file was sourced and are usable.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the other scripts in the same location on an Ubuntu machine I have access to, it is clear that these scripts should be proper shell scripts.  They should be executable and have a `#!`-line pointing to the correct interpreter.

Since you *expect* that the variable `drt` is set to something, you should check that it is actually set and that it's set to something reasonable. For example, if `$drt` is supposed to be the pathname of an existing directory:

```
if [ ! -d "$drt" ]; then
    echo 'drt is unset or does not contain path to directory' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Likewise for `rse`:

```
if [ -z "$rse" ]; then
    echo 'rse is unset' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This would be done at the start of the script.

### Dir checking

`pushd` and `popd` are primarily meant for interactive use (this may be argued about). It is additionally difficult to read and maintain a script that changes directories back and forth. Maybe not in this script, but in general.

Instead of changing working directory, doing something, and then changing back, you may use

```
( cd "some directory" && "some other command" )
```

The `cd` above is only affecting the `( ... )` subshell.

In this script, it may be enough with

```
if cd "$dir"; then
    command1
    command2
    # etc.
fi
```

assuming that `$drt` is an absolute path and that the simple command `$rse` is able to run correctly regardless of where it's started from (this leaves the the script in a modified working directory after the `if`-statement).  See the other scripts in `/etc/cron.daily/` to get view of how they do (the above suggestion is how the `/etc/cron.daily/dpkg` script does it, but it has no further commands after its `if`-statement).

The script would benefit from properly indenting the body of the `for`-loop and `if`-statement.

With the original example code, it can be done like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "$drt"/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
        wp plugin update --all --allow-root
        wp core update --allow-root
        wp language core update --allow-root
        wp theme update --all --allow-root
        popd
    fi
done
"$rse"
```

Indentation can be done either with spaces or tabs (it's a matter of taste).

Additionally, I mistyped your variable names several times while writing this. Having descriptive variable names is beneficial for both yourself (in a few weeks time) and for anyone else who is trying to figure out what your script is supposed to be doing. There is no benefit of using short variable names in scripts as it leads to obscure code. I'm furthermore uneasy about the fact that these variables are set elsewhere as it implies a dependency on something that is not known and not documented in the script.